# Why variable is not visible to other thread in synchronization?

Tags: java, multithreading

Let's assume I've two threads `t1` and `t2` which are trying to access `incX()`

Here is my following code:

```
    class Test implements Runnable {
    private int x  = 0;

    public void incX() {
    synchronized(this) {
    x = ++x; 
    }
    System.out.println("x is: "+x+"     "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
   }

    public void run() {
    incX();
}

 public static void main(String[] args)   {

   Thread t1 = new Thread(new Test());
   t1.start();
   Thread t2 = new Thread(new Test());
   t2.start();

}
```

Here's my output:

```
    x is: 1     Thread-1
    x is: 1     Thread-0
```

As in `incX()` method I've synchronized `x = ++x`, so the changes made to thread `t1` should be visible to thread `t2`, right? So my output should be:

```
    x is: 1     Thread-1
    x is: 2     Thread-0
```

I know `++x` is not an atomic operation but it is synchronized, so thread `t2` can't acquire the lock. So the threads should not `interleave` and changes made to `x` should be visible to thread `t2`, right? Am I misunderstanding?
So my question is why I am not getting the output:

```
     x is: 2     Thread-0
```

Comment: The real question here is why are you assigning the result of `++x` back to `x`? The whole point of the increment operators is that they write back to the variable.

Comment: Can you post some more of your code ? In particular, do you have 2 instances of your class ?

Comment: How are you running this code? You've shown two different threads, are they really using the same object and not two separate ones? The most likely explanation for the behavior you've described is that you're creating two separate instances.

Comment: I assigned `x = ++x` cause then my value of `++x` will be stored in `x`. So when thread `t1` release the lock then the value will be stored in `x` already.

Comment: I will edit my code.

Comment: @Hemlata The expression `++x` already writes back the incremented value into the variable _on its own_. No need to assign the value of this expression to the same variable again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using two **separate** instances of your `Test` class, so naturally the `x` in each of them only gets incremented once. It's effectively the same as this:

```
Test test1 = new Test();
Test test2 = new Test();
test1.incX();
test2.incX();
```

Since each instance of `Test` has its own `x`, you'll see `1` twice with that code too.

To test synchronized access to the **same** instance, you need to use a single instance instead. For example:

```
class Test {
    private int x  = 0;

    public void incX() {
        synchronized(this) {
            x = ++x;                         // See "Side Note" below
        }
        System.out.println("x is: "+x+"     "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();              // One instance
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            test.incX();                     // Used by this thread
        });
        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            test.incX();                     // And also by this one
        });
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Which will output

```
x is: 1     Thread-0
x is: 2     Thread-1
Done
```

or similar (naturally it varies depending on which thread gets scheduled when).

Sometimes, it'll even look like this:

```
x is: 2     Thread-0
x is: 2     Thread-1
Done
```

That's because the access to `x` in the `System.out.println` statement is *outside* the `synchronized` block, so sometimes (not always) `x` will get incremented after the end of the `synchronized` block and before the `println`:

```
synchronized(this) {
    x = ++x;
}
// ***The other thread can jump in here and increment x
System.out.println("x is: "+x+"     "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

In more detail:

1. `t1` enters the synchronized block
2. `t2` tries to enter the synchronized block but has to wait because `t1` has the lock
3. `t1` increments `x`, making it 1
4. `t1` exits the synchronized block
5. `t2` jumps in and increments `x`, making it 2
6. `t2` exits the synchronized block
7. `t1` outputs the *current* value of `x` (2)
8. `t2` outputs the *current* value of `x` (2)

Note that Step 2 and Step 3 could be in any order, and Steps 6-8 could also be in any order.

To reliably report `x` as it was within the synchronized block after being incremented, we'd want to either:

1. Move the `println` into the synchronized block

   ```
   public void incX() {
       synchronized(this) {
           x = ++x;                         // See "Side Note" below
           System.out.println("x is: "+x+"     "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
       }
   }
   ```

   or
2. Save the result of the increment in a local variable

   ```
   public void incX() {
       int y;                               // Local variable
       synchronized(this) {
           y = ++x;                         // No longer and odd thing to do
       }
       System.out.println("x is: "+y+"     "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
   }
   ```

Unless you have a really, really good reason to hold a synchronization lock during output, go with #2.

---

Side note: As I mentioned in a comment, `++x` *already* writes its value back to `x`, that's what the increment operators do. So the `x =` part of

```
x = ++x;
```

...is unnecessary. Either use the increment operator:

```
++x;
```

...or don't:

```
x += 1;
```

Comment: When i try to run your code, It outputs thread `t1` and `t2` both 2. Why?

Comment: @Hemlata: Because the access to `x` in the `System.out.println` statement is *outside* the `synchronized` block, so sometimes (not always) `x` will get incremented after the end of the `synchronized` block and before the `println`.

Comment: T.J. Crowder: If it do gets incremented then it should be 1 instead of 2 as I assigned `x` to 0. How could it increment two times?

Comment: @Hemlata: I've added further information to the answer to help explain that  a bit more

Comment: I got it. Cheers!

Comment: I've one more question. How is it possible that thread `t2` outputs 2 and then thread `t1` outputs 1? As thread `t2` already outputs 2 then the value of `x` should be 2. So how can thread `t1` can still output 1?

Comment: I removed the `t1.join` and `t2.join` then I was getting the output as first,   thread `t2 ` prints 2 and then thread `t1` prints 1. How is it possible?

Comment: Should I ask this as a different question or edit it in my current question?

Comment: @Hemlata: It's a different question. When/if you ask it, show exactly the code you're running, what output you're getting, etc. Remember that in the Java memory model, it's entirely possible for a thread to have a stale copy of a value. E.g.: Thread 1 updates `x` to `1`. Thread 1 *reads* `x` to pass it into `println`. Thread 2 updates `x` to `2`, reads its value, passes it to `println`, and `println` writes it. Then thread 1 writes the value it read earlier. (It can even get a stale read.) Fundamentally: The printlns aren't sync'd, so they don't behave like they're sync'd.